# BASH: Given a partial directory name ... how to cd into that directory

Tags: bash, cd-command

Having trouble with a bash script.
I need to `cd` into a directory using a partial name such as `binutil` where the full directory name might be `binutil-2.36`.

I need to do this so that as each package gets a new version I wont have to change my script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer to the question I linked in comments on [your previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324899/how-to-cd-using-partial-directory-path-and-wilds-card) ?

Comment: Yes I read thru both. I don't see a solution to my problem. Or perhaps I don't understand how they help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cd using partial directory path and wilds card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324899/how-to-cd-using-partial-directory-path-and-wilds-card)

Comment: That post is mine. I asked what was up. Once I understood there was an issue ... I posted this new question as I have been asked many times to do.

Comment: @keithbradley usually you post a new question when you have a follow-up question to an answer you got which diverges from the original question. However, there you haven't got any answers yet - only comments. So it's fine (and expected) that you edit the question in response to the comments instead of posting a new question.

Comment: @guiverc I just meant that your original approach (using a shell wildcard with `cd`) is still feasible provided you workaround the fact that, in recent versions of bash, `cd` no longer ignores excess arguments (by defining a `cd` function for example)

Comment: but as it turns out I was wrong ... seemed to work at the time I posted below ... but now does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never be able to [change the current path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-i-cant-change-directories-using-cd/) of the underlying session, only the session in which the *command* runs.
However, you can *source* your script: `source script.sh <dir>`

```bsh
read -d '' -r < <( \
find "${1:-.}" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'binutil-*' -print0 | sort -rVz) && cd "$REPLY"
```

Or create a function in `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`:

```
cd-binutil(){ # <dir>
    read -d '' -r < <( \
    find "${1:-.}" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'binutil-*' -print0 | sort -rVz) && cd "$REPLY"
}
```

`source ~/.bash_aliases` will apply the changes to the current session.

Comment: Thanks bac0n but I was unable to get this to work for me. I added your function but it does not seem to get me into that directory.

Comment: here is what I added in addition to your function:     cd-binutil   (next line)   touch foobar ... the file does not show up in that directory.

Comment: I take it all back ... turns out I needed to add sudo touch foobar.  THANKS bac0n !!

Comment: could you (or anyone) explain what the "${1:-.}" after 'find' does?

Comment: `${parameter:-word}` is a parameter expansion. Parameters that are unset or null will substitute to, in this case, `.` (current directory).